# Restrict access of a connected app (Salesforce)

Tags: authentication, salesforce, apex

What is the best way to restrict the scope of a connected app to a set of objects? My current solution is to use the `Manage user data via APIs` scope but that still grants more access than required.

A solution I see frequently is to create a user with a restricted profile and connect with that user but then you lose context of actions made by users in the connected app so this solution doesn't work

Comment: Only an idea on idea-exchange: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddU7UAJ/apply-crudfls-permissions-to-connected-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky, you typically don't. (consider posting on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, there might be a clever way I didn't think of).

You can flip the connected app from "all users can self authorise" to "admin-approved users are preauthorised" and then allow only certain profiles / permission sets to use the app. But the bulk of it is "just" enabling the connection via API and cutting it to say Chatter only or OpenId identifiers. And that's already an improvement compared to SOAP APIs where you don't have scopes and the app can completely impersonate the user, do everything they can do in UI.

Profiles/permission sets/sharing rules are "the" way even in not immediately obvious situations like Lighting Connect Salesforce to Salesforce or Named Credentials access to another org.

If you can't restrict the visibility with profiles and access to all tables user can see is not acceptable...

- you could create series of Apex classes exposing certain queries, updates etc and grant profile access to these classes - but without full api access? You could even let them pass any SOQL (evil) but use `with sharing, WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED, stripInaccessible` + custom restriction on tables before returning results
- you could look into https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm although I suspect it's run only on connect, not on every request. So at best you could deny access if user has right to see some sensitive data, not great
- if there are few objects you need to block updates if done via app - [Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm) might be the way to go. Throw error in a trigger if action started from REST context?
- give the [Transaction Security trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/enhanced_transaction_security/enhanced_transaction_security_basics) a go. If it looks promising (there's way to check "application" and "queried entities" according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types.htm&type=5)) - might be a solution. You'll likely have to cough up $ though, last time I checked the cool bits of event monitoring & transaction security were hidden behind an extra paid addon (standalone or bundled with platform encryption and Field Audit Track into Salesforce Shield solution)
- 2 logins? dedicated user for querying stuff but inserts/updates running as your end user?

Comment: Ok thank you for the response. I will stick with what I outlined in the question then. Kind of shocking sfdc doesn't have a better solution for this. A profile that can be assigned to the connected app itself would be ideal.

Comment: Yep, they even have profile and permission set assignment to the connected app, but only pull the assigned users from that. What a shame.

Comment: Be the change you want to see in the world, upvote https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddU7UAJ/apply-crudfls-permissions-to-connected-apps Only 8 years old lol